# UITableView not scrolling in time to see insert cell animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView cell. The numbers of rows is usually 6, but when an certain event is triggered this will increase to 7 and I want to insert a new row with animation at the bottom. Currently my code is like so:

(data source has been updated)

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:6, section: 0)], with: .left)
tableView.endUpdates()
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:6, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

This inserts the row and scrolls to the bottom but I can't see the cell animation properly. It's more like it inserts the cell and then scrolls after so I don't see it animating from the left. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This code for delete a row from table view with left animation . You can try with add row and also update table view in main thread .

```
 tableview.beginUpdates()
    var indexPathsToDeleteForAnimation: [NSIndexPath] = []
    var numOfCellsToRemove = ArrayOfItemsToRemove ?? 0

    // Do your work here
    while numOfCellsToRemove > 0 {
        // ...or here, if you need to add/remove the same amount of objects to/from somewhere
        indexPathsToDeleteForAnimation.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedCellIndex+numOfCellsToRemove, inSection: 0))
        numOfCellsToRemove -= 1
    }
    tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsToDeleteForAnimation, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Right)
    tableview.endUpdates()
```